# ScrollView childrens loses focus when scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a listview and button in a scrollview. When i scroll both list and button loses focus. When i tap on button it did not work but next time i tap it works i think button loses focus and focus is towards scrollview how to handle this please help

Answer (score 1):

Never put `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. `ListView` handles scrolling, and wrapping it in a `ScrollView` can cause problems with focus, touch-events etc. If you want other `Views` added to the top or bottom of you list, simply use [`ListView.addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) or [`ListView.addFooterView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view can have only one child, put your button and listview in common layout and try out.

Comment: thanks @ Apriya but my list and button are in a relativelayout which is single child in a scrollview